# Iframe covers navigation bar, needs close, open to fix?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a small webpage with a form, iframe-d in. When I put invalid input inside the form, the iframe covers up the navigation bar and I can't get the navigation bar back without closing and opening the page again.

Here is where I am (temporarily) hosting the webpage: dl.dropbox.com/u/1144456/rlp/v2/demo.html

the css stylesheet: dl.dropbox.com/u/1144456/rlp/v2/contact-us.htm

To recreate this problem, click the last tab and just click submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitting into a target element.  Remove this, allowing it to self-target, and it works fine.  In the form page, change:

```
<form action="#public" ...>
```

to

```
<form action="" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this the form doesn't work. 

Thanks for helping, though.